# Nativescript update value in DataForm

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am using code from this example [nativescript.org data form](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/DataForm/getting-started)
And the problem is the source object is not updating values in text fields.

`:source="person"` ,it takes values to build form from this object - source.

this looks like this

```
person: {
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  email: 'john@company.com',
  city: 'New York',
  street: '5th Avenue',
  streetNumber: 11,
}
```

and If I change value of `person.name = 'Mariola';` for example it would not change value in RadDataForm but in label it would update value.

here i made a demo [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TO4i2n)

I want to change value

```
 this.album.myRating = this.initVal;
```

it not working (something weird) anyway this is the problem. I want to load new data and then update DataForm values but it does not update.

so we have :source="person">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TO4i2n&v=4). You need to update the source object not only the property.

P.S. If you want to do the opposite i.e. change it from FORM and save object locally then you need to call **propertyCommitted**.

```
 <RadDataForm :source="person" @propertyCommitted="onPropertyCommitted" />
```

Comment: thank you it worked. How to got value of actual commited RadDataform field ? There is fired commited log but I need to commit mutation. I need the value of edited field. Property commited event has only these things  eventName: "propertyCommitted"
`JS: object: RadDataForm(940)
JS: editor: "undefined"
JS: entityProperty: EntityProperty(958)
JS: propertyName: "MANA"
JS: group: "undefined"
JS: groupName: "DefaultGroup"
JS: returnValue: "true"`

Comment: no now its now working can you check is there is any update version is causing the issue. I check play.nativescript.org your example its not updating form values its only updating label values and not the form.

Comment: somehting broken the myrating is not updating